# Iterm2 use Control + Option keys for C-M- key sequences

Tags: terminal-emacs, keystrokes

I usually use iTerm2 as a terminal emulator because of its tmux integration, which is extremely handy, but I haven't been able to find a way to get the Control + Option keys to work as a C-M- key in Emacs when I'm running it in the terminal. I think that it has something to do with the way that iTerm2 is sending the character sequences because it works fine when I use the Emacs GUI or when I run Emacs in MacOS's built-in terminal emulator.

This issue gets in my way in a few cases. Most frequently, it happens when I'm editing Clojure code and I try to type C-M-Space to select an expression or when I'm trying to use C-M-N or C-M-P to go to the next or previous expanded directory in a dired buffer.

The only settings in iTerm2 that seem to be relevant to me are these:

[image: iTerm2 Option key settings]

The `Esc+` option is the only one that generally works correctly when I'm using the Option key by itself, but it doesn't work when the control key is used at the same time.

Interestingly enough this does work when I'm running Emacs in Mac's terminal emulator. I do have the `Use Option as Meta key` setting checked in Mac's terminal emulator options. Just out of curiosity, I tried running `cat -v` in both Mac's terminal emulator and iTerm2 and pressed Control+Option+N just to compare the sequences; they were identical and what I would have expected:

iTerm2:

[image: cat -v in iTerm2]

MacOS's terminal emulator:

[image: cat -v in MacOS's terminal emulator]

At this point, I'm kind of stumped. The two terminal emulators must be sending the character sequences slightly differently, but I haven't been able to identify any differences yet.

I've found other questions online, but the answer in most cases is to create a custom keybinding in iTerm2 to send the character sequence that you want. If that's the solution then I'll just use a different terminal emulator.

Does anyone have any suggestions to help troubleshoot this?

Comment: I ended up filing an issue with iTerm2. The author made a change that mostly did what I wanted it to. Please see https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/9962 for details.